# We all know the difference, but: can 'all' ever substitute for 'both?'

Tags: differences

I was wondering whether there is a formal rule for or against substituting 'all' for 'both'?

We all know the difference between 'all' and 'both', but look at this question from ELL:

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83143/all-vs-both

Here there are answers to the effect that *both* shall always refer to 2 things, and *all* can refer to **more than one** -- is that definition of 'all' widely accepted, and if it thus overlaps with 'both', can 'all' substitute for 'both' at least in certain cases?

> Example 1 (2 is specified) :
>
> he has 2 shirts -- both of them are white
>
> he has 2 shirts; **all** of them are white
>
> Example 2 (2 is implied) :
>
> He crashed his bike. Both the wheels were smashed.
>
> He crashed his bike. ALL the wheels were smashed.

**I know that** *'both' sounds better whetever clearly applicable*, but can 'all' ever substitute for 'both',  or is there a clear grammatical rule / convention that *"thou shalt not use 'all' wherever 'both' is applicable?"*

Comment: "How y'all doin'?"

Comment: If it's not important that there are precisely two, and if it's not necessary to mention this fact in every sentence, then _all_ covers the territory from zero on up.

Comment: @Hot Licks thanks, that's one way to refer to 2 people, right!

Comment: @John Lawler Thank you, but I am referring to situations where 'two' is implicitly known. Specifically I should like to know whether 'both' is to be preferred to 'all' *wherever applicable?*

Comment: **Both** means **two**, and it strictly refers to *two* - not less and not more. Suppose, you have only two shirts and you haven't explicitly mentioned that number. Then you can say *all your shirts*. But once you have mentioned *two shirts*, you have to refer to them as *both* in positive sentences and *neither* in negative sentences. If you say *my bike got crashed and all the wheels were smashed*, there is an implication that you had a 'three-wheeler' bike! Normally a bike implies a two-wheeler vehicle, so the use of *both the wheels* is unambiguous as well as correct.

Comment: @mahmud koya Thanks a lot for your 'unambiguous as well as correct' reply!

Comment: @EnglishStudent - I'm sure some people would use "y'all" even for one person. About 10 years ago there was an email doing the rounds with instructions on how to speak like a Southerner (from Southern USA); it said that "y'all" was singular and "all y'all" was plural. Though I believe it was a bit tongue-in-cheek I don't think it was incorrect that "y'all" *can* be singular. Any Southerners who want to correct me (and tell me that I fell for an obvious joke) please go ahead!

Comment: @AndyT Y'all **best** not be laffin' -- very nice! In fact it is a well accepted singular / plural in the vernacular and made famous by numerous novels and movies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the set has a known number of objects and that number is known to be two, you should use "both". Using "all" will sound unnatural, and it may even cause confusion (by implying you are talking about something else).

When in doubt, avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought. I would appreciate it even more if you could find me some rule that explicitly says so, which would completely answer my question.

Comment: English doesn't have a formal governing body, so I'm not going to be able to find you an official rule.

Comment: Official rule is not needed. I HAVE not even found a ruling in a style guide! Please note: I have down- voted your answer by mistake. Kindly make some minor edit in your answer (any small letter or punctuation) so that the software will allow me to correct the error.

Comment: Well I think any style guide would support the notion of reducing ambiguity.

Comment: VERY TRUE. It is probably to be understood as self-evident, and therefore not specified. Thanks a lot for your clear answer, and don't forget to make that minor edit!

Answer (score 0):

*All* can indeed be used to refer to everything in a set containing two elements.

It is even possible to say "all two", for example:

> I felt bad for taking all two chicken legs and not leaving anything for you, but I was just so hungry.

Yes, it might sound a little weird, but there's no rule against it, and if you're the sort of person who likes logical preciseness, you might be more likely to use "all" in place of "both" in certain circumstances.

Comment: It is certainly a very nice example and very appropriate within its own context, when 'two' is 'all' there is -- thanks a lot for adding a fresh dimension!

Comment: It does sound weird. This is about language, not about logic. No one talks like that. (By the same "logic", you could also say "*all zero people talk like that*".)

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I'm looking at the intersection of math (logic) and language.  But I promise not to try to force you to do that!